# Calculating size in paragraphs from an address, as a NASM constant expression

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I am converting an assembly language program from A86 assembler to the NASM assembler.

I have most of the program converted except this line

```
mov bx, (stack_end / 10h) + 1
```

The bss section is defined as follows

```
section .bss
     stack_start    resb    07feh           ; create stack almost 2k in size
     stack_end      equ     $ - 1
```

The error nasm is throwing when I build is

```
division operator may only be applied to scaler values
```

I have debugged the application and seen what value it is actually calculating and could just plug that number in but would rather keep the existing logic if possible. Plus it would be a good learning experience.

This is part of a DOS 16-bit COM executable. I know what you're asking, why am I converting it, well the open source project owner has requested that all assembly language programs be converted to NASM since it is more widely supported.

EDIT:

I am compiling with nasm -fbin.

The code can be seen here, minus the conversion to nasm syntax.

https://gitlab.com/FreeDOS/util/switchar/-/blob/master/SOURCE/SWITCHAR/SWITCHAR.S

I used jesters comment ((stack_end - stack_start / 10h) + 1 and the error went away but like stated it would be 80h, the original value is 103h

Comment: COM programs don't even have sections to start with. It's unclear what that calculation wants to load especially since COM files are also not relocated. Sounds like it's trying to come up with some sort of paragraph size for the stack, for that `((stack_end - stack_start) / 10h) + 1` may work if you expect the result to be `80h`.

Comment: NASM with the multi-section bin output format requires you to use proper label arithmetic to calculate things like this. This is required because NASM's internal linker doesn't allow for arbitrary calculations. For example, you need `(stack_end - stack_start + code_end - code_start + 256 + 15) / 16` if the length you want to include has the PSP (`org 256`) plus a code section (stretching from offset 0100h up to the stack) plus this stack section. [Here's some code](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/callver/file/55bf60a4fea0/callver.asm#l16) using label arithmetic (in a single section).

Comment: [Here's another example](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/tsr/file/daca203fa216/transien.asm#l972), in this case all sections' sizes are paragraph aligned so we can just add up the individual sizes to get a valid length in paragraphs. [Here's yet another example](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/ldebug/file/c2d96de77120/source/debug.asm#l127), this one uses several sections (data entry, data stack, code, init) and there's more label arithmetic done overall.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: It looks like they may want to shrink their memory block to a known stack (which we hope is below the stack they were given by the OS). This is useful eg for some TSRs or when you want to execute a child process.

Comment: I assume this value is going to be moved into SS (is that why `/ 10h`?), then `mov SP, 2048`?  But why? This space will still be part of the initial 64k a `.com` program gets, so you could just `mov sp, stack_end` to point at it without changing SS.  Is it useful to have a smaller SP value for some reason, like to detect stack overflow from SP wrapping at 0? (Thoughts, @ecm?) According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file#DOS_binary_format, `.com` programs start with SP = `FFFCh` or `FFFEh`, so you initially have 64k - program_size bytes of stack, but I guess you want it elsewhere.

Comment: @ecm: Thanks, I wondered about a TSR, I guess that's plausible.  I'm still unclear on what the point of dividing an offset by `16` would be.  To point SP at somewhere in your BSS, you'd just `mov sp, stack_end`.  But that's still an offset from the non-zero SS; maybe this code is going to get the current SS value and add that to get a new SS:SP?  Yeah, I think that could actually work.   Seems like a bunch of work for zero benefit, though.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Two things. First, a .COM style flat executable can be loaded into a memory block (usually an UMB then) with less than 64 KiB in size. In that case the initial `sp` is not equal to FFFEh. Second, I assume they're setting up the size-in-paragraphs in `bx` for passing it to DOS service interrupt 21h function 4Ah (resize memory block). To be fair, they may also use it to address a different segment based on their `cs`, eg `mov bx, paragraphs` \ `mov ax, cs` \ `add ax, bx`. Either can have uses.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: The offset of the end of a section corresponds to the size of a memory block. If you divide by 16 and add 1 then you are calculating the size of a memory block, in paragraphs, rounded up. In my comment I first added 15 then divided by 16, which does the rounding in a slightly different way but otherwise works in the same way to obtain a size in paragraphs.

Comment: @ecm: Ah, ok, wasn't aware of how DOS memory-management functions worked.  Hopefully your `bx` arg for DOS idea is right; If they wanted to add it to something, going to all this work to make it an assemble-time constant would be half wasted if they didn't `add ax, paragraphs`.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: You are right about using `add` with an immediate if you have a build time constant. However, do consider that back in the bad old days people often calculated the entire constant at run time, eg [in the old callver](https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/callver/file/09e933418542/callver.asm#l15) before I changed it.

Comment: @ecm: Is `$ - $$` perhaps useful here, to get a pure number?  Just like how the manual explains why `510-$` won't work as the control for a `times` directive, instead requiring `510-($-$$)`: https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo13.html#section-13.1.4.  I guess that still requires manually adding in the `org`, though, and maybe makes things worse or more confusing if you're switching sections.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Yes, if you put it at the right spot and in the right section then what I called `code_end - code_start` can be replaced by `$ - $$`. In a single section the `$$` will evaluate to a symbol at the offset equal to the `org` value, but (like a regular label) not as a scalar.

Comment: @ecx: Oh right, and/or one could do `stack_size equ $ - 1 - stack_start` on the spot after the `resb`, instead of defining a `stack_end` symbol and doing the subtraction later.  But that's not the absolute offset of the end of the stack.  No way to do `stack_end - code_start` when they're in different sections, I guess.  It's tantalizingly close: `mov bx, stack_end - code_start` does assemble to `mov bx,0x804` in a toy example I tried, but reduction to a numeric value happens too late for `mov bx, (stack_end - code_start) / 16` to work.  https://godbolt.org/z/GdMco96dq won't disas -fbin :/